# AWS dynamoDb pagination with limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to paginate the entries from a table created in dynamoDb
Is there anyway to check if the table items have been exceeded.

For instance if I make a call to fetch items from the table I get the following error

```
PANIC: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 51 [running]:
github.com/urfave/negroni.(*Recovery).ServeHTTP.func1(0xdfae028, 0xc000186028, 0xc0002162d0, 0xc000154200)
    /Users/hammadali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/negroni@v1.0.0/recovery.go:159 +0xcb
panic(0x498ea20, 0x51f4410)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.5/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
github.com/prohousing-as/ph-supplier-service/application.(*SupplierService).GetAllSuppliers(0xc0002cc300, 0xc00002a270, 0x24, 0xbb8, 0xc0004403e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/hammadali/source/ph-supplier-service/application/supplier_service.go:41 +0x330
github.com/prohousing-as/ph-supplier-service/ui.(*SupplierController).GetAllSupplier(0xc000526ed0, 0xdfae028, 0xc000186028, 0xc0003be300)
    /Users/hammadali/source/ph-supplier-service/ui/supplier_controller.go:40 +0x139
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000527170, 0xdfae028, 0xc000186028, 0xc0003be300)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.5/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2041 +0x44
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0002e40c0, 0xdfae028, 0xc000186028, 0xc0003be100)
    /Users/hammadali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.4/mux.go:210 +0xe2
```

Function fetching all the Items

```
// fetches the items from dynamoDb and stores it in res
res, err := s.SupplierRepo.GetAllSupplier(uuid, limit)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("from application: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    item := &domain.SupplierTableItems{}
    all := &domain.AllSupplierItems{}
    // Looping over the result and appending it on the list
    for _, i := range res.Items {
        err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(i, item)
        all.Collection = append(all.Collection, *item)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
    // storing lastEvaluatedKey for pagination
    all.LastEvaluatedKey = *res.LastEvaluatedKey["uuid"].S
    return all, nil
```

Is there anyway to check if the call made to fetch the items has exceeded the table entries and just provide the number of entries left.

Comment: You need to show your code, especially around line 41 of `supplier_service.go` (and probably its caller). This is not just an API question, you're misusing an object and attempting to dereference a `nil` pointer.

Comment: I have added the code of the function being used to fetch the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has not much to do with DynamoDB's pagination, you are simply trying to access something that's not there, somewhere around `/Users/hammadali/source/ph-supplier-service/application/supplier_service.go:41`

To answer your question otherwise: yes, DynamoDB tells you when it's done paginating. [From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html):

> - If the result contains a LastEvaluatedKey element and it's non-null, proceed to step 2.
> - If there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result, there are no more items to be retrieved.

Comment: Thank you. If table contains 10 items and you set the limit to 6 at a time. In the first call I get 6 items and LastEvaluatedKey. Second call with ExclusiveStartKey as LastEvaluatedKey will through invalid memory error. Is there a work around for that?

Comment: @HammadAli Read the answer carefully, it's quite clear - "If there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result, there are no more items to be retrieved.". But you're still asking: "Second call with ExclusiveStartKey as LastEvaluatedKey will through invalid memory error. Is there a work around for that?". The solution is to check if there's an `LastEvaluatedKey` field in the response - if not, you're finished paging.

Comment: @HammadAli you should mark this answer as accepted as it is 100% the answer to your question...

Comment: I am afraid this does not solve my problem. I am trying to find a way to handle the error when the items in the table are less than call in the query. As at the moment it is giving me invalid memory address.

Comment: Again. If there are 400 items, Step 1: I query 300 items; I get 300 items and LastEvaluatedKey. Step 2: I query 300 items with LastEvaluatedKey; The program panics with invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference. I want the program to output the remaining 100 items without LastEvaluatedKey

Comment: Your question was specifically: is there a way to check if the call has exceeded the table entries. The answer is definitely: yes, there is, see my answer above. If your question is: why does my code crash, then ask a different question. I have answered your question. You are just asking the wrong question, but that's not really on me, is it?